# Combinación Groupby y Aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Muy buenas gente,

Tengo un dataframe con tres columnas: continente, pais y población.

Me gustaría mediante un groupby, crear una nueva tabla con los paises agrupados por continente y por tanto añadir a esa tabla: el número de paises que se han agrupado, el sumatorio de la población de los paises que se han agrupado, la media y la std.

Es decir la solución seria una tabla con indice los continentes y de columnas: "count", "sum", "mean" y "std".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quiza estas lineas te puedan ayduar.

Lo primero es tener un DataFrame con la información con la cual trabajaremos. Use solo un par de paises para dar un ejemplo.

```
import pandas as pd

# Ver datos en: https://www.sport-histoire.fr/es/Geografia/Paises_por_poblacion.php
continentes = ['Asia', 'Asia', 'América', 'Asia', 'América', 'Asia', 'África', 'Asia', 'Europa', 'América', 'Asia', 'África', 'Asia', 'África', 'Asia', 'África', 'Europa']
paises = ['China', 'India', 'Estados Unidos', 'Indonesia', 'Brasil', 'Pakistán', 'Nigeria', 'Bangladés', 'Rusia', 'México', 'Japón', 'Etiopía', 'Filipinas', 'Egipto', 'Vietnam', 'República Democrática del Congo', 'Alemania']
personas = [1415045928,1354051854,326766748,266794980,210867954,200813818,195875237,166368149,143964709,130759074,127185332,107534882,106512074,99375741,96491146,84004989,82293457]
```

En las lineas anteriores, tenemos las listas de los continentes y las agrupamos (como columnas), el un dataframe que llamaremos ("df")

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(continentes, paises, personas)), columns=['Continente','Pais','Poblacion'])
```

> *Si tienes la información fila a fila, puedes comentar las lineas anteriores y crearias el dataframe como se muestra a continuación*

```
## Tambien se puede crear el DataFrame de la siguiente manera
#informacion = [["Asia","China", 1415045928],["Asia","India", 1354051854]]
#df = pd.DataFrame(informacion, columns=['Continente','Pais','Poblacion'])
```

Con los datos, ya en el DataFrame, puedes visualizarlos de la siguiente forma (es solo un convencionalismo), esta parte es opcional...

```
# Visualización (Opcional)
print("\nDataFrame agrupado por continentes:")
print( df.groupby(['Continente', 'Pais']).size() )
```

Para realizar todo en una sola linea, necesitamos tener algunas columnas duplicadas, así, primero realizaremos una copia del DataFrame original (por si lo necesitas utilizar más adelante y mantenerlo intacto; tambien podriamos trabajar directamente sobre "df", sin necesidad de crear este nuevo dataframe, eso queda a tu consideración)

```
# Nuevo DataFrame, contiene los datos del DataFrame original
continentes_agrup = df
```

Duplicamos, los datos de la columna población, para calcular la media y la desviación standard. Tambien duplicamos la columna pais, para realizar el conteo de los paises que conforman cada continente.

```
# Se duplicaran algunas columnas (para relizar calculos de media y conteo de agrupacion)
continentes_agrup['Media'] = df['Poblacion']
continentes_agrup['Desviacion_Std'] = df['Poblacion']
continentes_agrup['Nro_de_paises'] = df['Pais']
```

Y por ultimo, realizamos la agrupación y realizamos los calculos correspondientes. La magia de Pandas, ocurre en la siguiente linea:

```
continentes_agrup = continentes_agrup.groupby(['Continente']).agg({'Poblacion':'sum', 'Media':'mean', 'Desviacion_Std':'std', 'Nro_de_paises':'count'}).reset_index()
print(continentes_agrup)
```

***Así... el código completo seria:***

```
import pandas as pd

# Ver datos en: https://www.sport-histoire.fr/es/Geografia/Paises_por_poblacion.php
continentes = ['Asia', 'Asia', 'América', 'Asia', 'América', 'Asia', 'África', 'Asia', 'Europa', 'América', 'Asia', 'África', 'Asia', 'África', 'Asia', 'África', 'Europa']
paises = ['China', 'India', 'Estados Unidos', 'Indonesia', 'Brasil', 'Pakistán', 'Nigeria', 'Bangladés', 'Rusia', 'México', 'Japón', 'Etiopía', 'Filipinas', 'Egipto', 'Vietnam', 'República Democrática del Congo', 'Alemania']
personas = [1415045928,1354051854,326766748,266794980,210867954,200813818,195875237,166368149,143964709,130759074,127185332,107534882,106512074,99375741,96491146,84004989,82293457]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(continentes, paises, personas)), columns=['Continente','Pais','Poblacion'])

## Tambien se puede crear el DataFrame de la siguiente manera
#informacion = [["Asia","China", 1415045928],["Asia","India", 1354051854]]
#df = pd.DataFrame(informacion, columns=['Continente','Pais','Poblacion'])

# Visualización (Opcional)
print("\nDataFrame agrupado por continentes:")
print( df.groupby(['Continente', 'Pais']).size() )

# Nuevo DataFrame, contiene los datos del DataFrame original
continentes_agrup = df

# Se duplicaran algunas columnas (para relizar calculos de media y conteo de agrupacion)
continentes_agrup['Media'] = df['Poblacion']
continentes_agrup['Desviacion_Std'] = df['Poblacion']
continentes_agrup['Nro_de_paises'] = df['Pais']

continentes_agrup = continentes_agrup.groupby(['Continente']).agg({'Poblacion':'sum', 'Media':'mean', 'Desviacion_Std':'std', 'Nro_de_paises':'count'}).reset_index()
print(continentes_agrup)
```

***Y el resultado que obtendrías seria algo así:***

```
  Continente   Poblacion         Media  Desviacion_Std  Nro_de_paises
0    América   668393776  2.227979e+08    9.854692e+07              3
1       Asia  3733263281  4.666579e+08    5.694195e+08              8
2     Europa   226258166  1.131291e+08    4.360816e+07              2
3     África   486790849  1.216977e+08    5.040470e+07              4
```